# How to create a specific json object in Perl

Tags: json, perl, sigma.js

I am writing a script that allows to create a json object with information of a specific graph to use with SigmaJS.

It is important to emphasize that the user must indicate how many iterations must be done to define the number of nodes that will exist in the graph.
I am new in this language, in the code place the iterations in 5 just for example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
my $json_obj = new JSON;
my %perl_data;


for (my $i=0; $i <= 5 ; $i++) {
    $perl_data{nodes} = [{id => "..", label => "..", label => "..", x => ".." , y => ".." , size => ".."}];
    $perl_data{edges} = [{id => "..", source => "..", target => "..", color => ".."}];
}


print $json_obj->pretty->encode(\%perl_data);
```

I get this result:

```
{
   "nodes" : [
      {
         "x" : "..",
         "id" : "..",
         "y" : "..",
         "label" : "..",
         "size" : ".."
      }
   ],
   "edges" : [
      {
         "target" : "..",
         "id" : "..",
         "color" : "..",
         "source" : ".."
      }
   ]
}
```

But I need something like that:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "n0",
      "label": "A node",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "size": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "n1",
      "label": "Another node",
      "x": 3,
      "y": 1,
      "size": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "n2",
      "label": "And a last one",
      "x": 1,
      "y": 3,
      "size": 1
    }
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "id": "e0",
      "source": "n0",
      "target": "n1"
    },
    {
      "id": "e1",
      "source": "n1",
      "target": "n2"
    },
    {
      "id": "e2",
      "source": "n2",
      "target": "n0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are repeatedly setting `$perl_data{nodes}` and `$perl_data{edges}` rather than adding to arrays referenced by them.

```
my %perl_data = (
   nodes => [],
   edges => [],
);

for my $i (0..5) {
   push @{ $perl_data{nodes} }, {
      id    => "..",
      label => "..",
      x     => "..",
      y     => "..",
      size  => "..",
   };

   push @{ $perl_data{edges} }, {
      id     => "..",
      source => "..",
      target => "..",
      color  => "..",
   };
}
```